# InDesign cross reference link to a paragraph in a repeating table header

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a bunch of tables where I'm using a title paragraph in the header as cross references in a table of contents. Some of these tables are quite long so I have the header set to be repeating so when I need to have the table continue on another page, all the header stuff is there as well.

The issue I'm having is that when I export as an interactive PDF and attempt to click one of the links in the table of contents, it takes me to the last instance of that repeated paragraph instead of the first one. The page number displayed in the table of contents is the first instance, as expected.

Is there a menu somewhere that I'm missing to control this behavior?

Let me know if there's any more details I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a specific paragraph style for just table of contents. I create a booklet with several pages that have the same header, "Standard Booth Furniture".

The first page I have a paragraph style called "ToC - Booth Furnishings". I apply that paragraph style for every unique page that the TOC should link to. For every duplicate header, I apply a paragraph style called "Section Header". This has the same information as the ToC - Booth Furnishing paragraph style but will not show up in the ToC. When I create my ToC, I only use the paragraph style "ToC - Booth Furnishings" to get the first page of each section.